Householder matrices are unitary
In this answer, it is proven that Householder matrices are unitary. However, there's no explanation for that step
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{ww^\dagger ww^\dagger}{w^\dagger ww^\dagger w}
=\frac{ww^\dagger}{w^\dagger w}
\\
\end{align}
$$
Why does it hold truth?

Let $z=w^{\dagger }w$. As a scalar, it can be brought out in front of the
numerator, and it then cancels
$$
\frac{ww^{\dagger }ww^{\dagger }}{w^{\dagger }ww^{\dagger }w}=\frac{%
wzw^{\dagger }}{zw^{\dagger }w}=\frac{zww^{\dagger }}{zw^{\dagger }w}=\frac{%
ww^{\dagger }}{w^{\dagger }w}
$$
